# how to add text watermark and convert video to 3gp with FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, 3gp

how to add text watermark and convert a video flv to 3gp with FFMPEG?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to convert flv to 3gp:

ffmpeg -i input.flv -s 176x144 -vcodec h263 -r 15 -b 200 -ab 12.8 -acodec amr_nb -ar 8000 output.3gp

Comment: thank you mahmudul. do you have any command to add text watermark for a video via ffmpeg?

Comment: @lakshanz - I do not know about it.. I actually did not understand what you mean by add text watermark.

Comment: @lakshanz - You can look at this link http://goinggnu.wordpress.com/2007/05/07/watermark-videos-with-ffmpeg/ ...